# Permalinks causing wp-json to 405

Tags: permalinks, ajax

I have 3 sites I am working with and only the main domain is having this disruption.

We have a staging site with no issues, and another subdomain with no issues as well. The main domain when updating certain plugins is coming back with a 405 rest_forbidden error.  Our staging site has all the same plugins, same install version of Wordpress and same Theme, accept no issues. Our other site has the same theme and some same plugins as well but no errors as well.

The fix (but its not a perfect fix).
On the primary domain when I set the permalinks to plain the wp-json error goes away completely. I have to switch it back for seo purposes which returns the issue.

Things I have done to attempt to resolve this.

- Remove all htaccess code and replace with install htaccess code
- Removed all plugins accept the primary fault plugin (no success)
- Checked for any code that may be custom in the functions.php (no success).

Thank you for your help

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean all pages/URLs give a 405 rest forbidden error? Or do you mean just all REST API endpoints say 405 forbidden? HTAccess has nothing to do with this.

Comment: How do main and staging site differ in server setup?